# Merge two maps with Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two maps like this:

```
map1 = new Map<String, MyObject>();
map2 = new Map<String, MyObject>();

MyObject {
   Integer mark1;
   Integer mark2;
}
```

What I want to do to is to merge the two maps into a `map3` `<String, MyObject>` like this:

1. If `map1.place` is not in `map2.place`, then I add the entry to `map3`.
2. same if `map2.place` is not in `map1.place`, I add the entry to `map3`.
3. if `map1.place` is in `map2.place`, then I add this entry:

- `map1.place, (map1.mark1, map2.mark2)`

I have read about `flatMap`, but I really have a hard time using it.
Any clue how to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is what I think would work

```
Map<String, MyObj> map3 = new HashMap<>(map1);
map2.forEach(
    (key, value) -> map3.merge(key, value, (v1, v2) -> new MyObject(v1.mark1,v2.mark2))
);
```

The merge function is what is taking care of your scenario 3, in that if the key already exists, it creates a new MyObject with v1.mark1 and v2.mark2

Answer (score 29):

It can be done using the [`Stream API`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) with the appropriate `mergeFunction` as next:

```
Map<String, MyObject> map3 = Stream.of(map1, map2)
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Map.Entry::getValue,
            (v1, v2) -> new MyObject(v1.getMark1(), v2.getMark2())
        )
    );
```

This concatenates entries of `map1` followed by the entries of `map2`, then convert everything as a `Map` with a merge function that will use `mark1` from the first value (the one from `map1`) and  `mark2` from the second value (the one from `map2`) in case of duplicate keys.

---

Or it could also be done using a different `Supplier<Map>` that will propose a map that already contains the entries of `map1` then we can focus only on adding the entries of `map2` as next:

```
Map<String, MyObject> map3 = map2.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Map.Entry::getValue,
            (v1, v2) -> new MyObject(v1.getMark1(), v2.getMark2()),
            () -> new HashMap<>(map1)
        )
    );
```

Comment: Yes, this was the other way I was thinking of doing it, I the only reason I went against it, was if they go with a parallel stream, then it might not come out correctly as you cant guarantee the order, so then the final merge may not be correct

Comment: @AshFrench parallel stream doesn't make much sense for such a simple task, you would pay the price of using several threads and synchronizing them even with big maps, I don't believe that it would be faster

Comment: @AshFrench the new approach will work even with parallel streams even if it doesn't make much sense

Comment: @Ash French: which ordering issue are you thinking of, that could arise with this approach, but not with your solution?

Comment: No, this will totally work with parallel streams; they don't lose their ordering.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: there’s the subtle aspect that `Stream.concat` will only report an `ORDERED` characteristic if both source streams do, which implies that if at least one input map is, e.g. a `HashMap`, the resulting stream is unordered, so you can’t rely on map1’s elements being processed before map2’s. So for this case, you’d better replace `Stream.concat(map1.entrySet().stream(), map2.entrySet().stream())` with `Stream.of(map1, map2).flatMap(m->m.entrySet().stream())`…

Comment: Typo: in `.flatMap(map -> map1.entrySet().stream())`, map1 should be map. SO rejects my edit for being too small :/

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work.

```
Map<String, MyObject> result = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();

Set<String> allKeys = new HashSet<String>();
allKeys.addAll(map1.keySet());
allKeys.addAll(map2.keySet());
for(String key : allKeys){
    MyObject v1 = map1.get(key);
    MyObject v2 = map2.get(key);
    if(v1 != null && v2 == null){
        result.put(key, v1);
    }else if(v1 == null && v2 !=null){
        result.put(key, v2);
    } else {
        MyObject newObject = new MyObject(v1.mark1, v2.mark2); 
        result.put(key, newObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Incase of a simple merge you could use `map3.putAll()` as explained in [How can I combine two HashMap objects containing the same types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299728/how-can-i-combine-two-hashmap-objects-containing-the-same-types)

In your case, you would probably have to write some custom logic,

First populate map3 with map1.  Then Iterate the map3 to find any duplicates with map2 in which case you replace the entry with the `map1.place, (map1.mark1, map2.mark2)` logic.

**MapMerge**

```
public class MapMerge {

    public static void main(String []args){


        Map<String, MyObject> map1 = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();
        Map<String, MyObject> map2 = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();
        Map<String, MyObject> map3 = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();

        map3.putAll(map1);

        for(Entry<String, MyObject> entry:map2.entrySet()){         
            if (map3.containsKey(entry.getKey())){                  
                MyObject map3Obj = map3.get(entry.getKey());
                map3.put(
                    entry.getKey(), 
                    new MyObject(map3Obj.getMark1(),entry.getValue().getMark2())
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MyObject**

```
class MyObject{

    public MyObject(Integer m1, Integer m2){
        mark1 = m1;
        mark2 = m2;
    }

    public Integer getMark1() {
        return mark1;
    }
    public void setMark1(Integer mark1) {
        this.mark1 = mark1;
    }
    public Integer getMark2() {
        return mark2;
    }
    public void setMark2(Integer mark2) {
        this.mark2 = mark2;
    }
    Integer mark1;
    Integer mark2;
}
```

Comment: have you seen in java 8 the `map.merge()` function, it basically allows you to do the `if(contains){get() put()}` into one call

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:  Given a List of Maps. Then Join the maps according to the Key

```
    public class Test14 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Map<String, List<Integer>> m1 = new HashMap<>();
            Map<String, List<Integer>> m2 = new HashMap<>();
            m1.put("a", List.of(1));
            m1.put("b", List.of(2, 3));
            m2.put("a", List.of(12, 115));
            m2.put("b", List.of(2, 5));
            m2.put("c", List.of(6));

            System.out.println("map1 => " + m1);
            System.out.println("map2 => " + m2);

            ArrayList<Map<String, List<Integer>>> maplist = new ArrayList<Map<String, List<Integer>>>();
            maplist.add(m1);
            //   map1 => {a=[1], b=[2, 3]}
            maplist.add(m2);
            //      map2 => {a=[12, 115], b=[2, 5], c=[6]}

            System.out.println("maplist => " + maplist);
         //    maplist => [{a=[1], b=[2, 3]}, {a=[12, 115], b=[2, 5], c=[6]}]


            //  flatmap does omitted {} 
            List<Entry<String, List<Integer>>> collect11 = 
                    maplist
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(" collect11  => " + collect11);
            // collect11  => [a=[1], b=[2, 3], a=[12, 115], b=[2, 5], c=[6]]

            // That's why we will use this flatmap


            Map<String, List<Integer>> map2 = maplist.stream()
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())

            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            //keyMapper 
                            Map.Entry::getKey,


                            //valueMapper
                            Map.Entry::getValue,

                            (list_a,list_b) -> Stream.concat(list_a.stream(), list_b.stream())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())


                            )//tomap

                    );
//{a=[1, 12, 115], b=[2, 3, 2, 5], c=[6]}

            System.out.println("After joining the maps according the key  => " + map2);
            // After joining the maps according the key  => {a=[1, 12, 115], b=[2, 3, 2, 5], c=[6]}

            /*
             OUTPUT :

             After joining the maps according the key  => {a=[1, 12, 115], b=[2, 3, 2, 5], c=[6]}
             */

        }// main

    }
```