# Is there any way to reduce some code noise using java stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two classes:

```
public class Cat
{
   public Cat(UUID id, String name)
   {
     this.id = id;
     this.name = name;
   }

   @Getter
   UUID id;

   @Getter
   String name;
}

public class Animal
{
   @Getter
   UUID id;

   @Getter
   String name;
}
```

And I have two maps:

```
Map<Cat, Location> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<Animal, Location> map2 = new HashMap<>();
```

I need to easily convert `map2` data into a `map`. I was able to do it with the following code:

```
for (Entry<Animal, Location> entry : map2.entrySet())
{
   UUID id = entry.getKey().getId();
   String name = entry.getKey().getName();

   Cat key = new Cat(id, name);
   map.put(key, entry.getValue());
}

return map;
```

Is there a better way to do this or is the approach I'm taking ok?

Comment: Yes there is. Have you tried reading the javadoc of Stream? Or one of the many tutorials explaining how streams work, and what you can do with them (like map() and collect())? You will learn **a lot** by reading the documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two maps with Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40158605/merge-two-maps-with-java-8)

Comment: Also [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038673/merging-two-mapstring-integer-with-java-8-stream-api).

Comment: Consider `map2.forEach((k, v) -> map.put(new Cat(k.getId(), k.getName()), v))`, but also consider dispensing with the maps and adding `location` to `Animal`, since the use of a Map seems to imply that each Animal has one location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collectors.toMap` as :

```
Map<Cat, Location> map = map2.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                entry -> new Cat(entry.getKey().getId(), entry.getKey().getName()),
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                (a, b) -> b));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `toMap()` collector with the merge overload :

```
Map<Cat, Location> map =
map2.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(toMap(e-> new Cat(e.getKey().getId()), entry.getKey().getName(), 
                   Entry::getValue, (a,b)->b ));
```

Or maybe simpler without stream :

```
Map<Cat, Location> map = new HashMap<>();
map2.forEach( (k,v) -> map.put(new Cat(k.getId(), k.getName()), v) );
```